# How to increment version numbers in GitHub Protected Branches?

Tags: github, versioning

I am looking for a good process to manage the version number of my project when my master branch has GitHub branch protection turned on.

In an ideal world, when you merge to your 'release' branch your continuous integration server would run its tests then automatically increment the version number of your project and commit back to your SCM system.

However, with branch protection, you cannot commit to your branch without a Pull Request, so you have a catch-22 where your CI server cannot push to your protected branch when it tries to update the version number.

I can think of a few work arounds, all of which are sub optimal:

1. Rig up a system so your CI server would make a PR to update the version. I'm not sure if you can even do that with GitHub, but even if it is that ends up creating two Pull Requests for every one 'real' PR, which is awkward.
2. Remove Branch Protection - now anyone can push anything to the branches, and you have to manage your developers through a *manual process*
3. Update the version manually before the pull request. this is slightly better than #2, but it opens the door for developers to make mistakes when choosing the new version number, or merging the right version number to the wrong branch.

I'm hoping there are other options I haven't thought of.

We are using Javascript and npm, but I believe the problem is language agnostic, certainly the same problem would exist with Java and Maven for example.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I have the same issue.  I found an action to increment my version but it fails when I try to push back because the branch is protected.

Answer (score 4):

I used `git tags` to automate versioning using Jenkins. So every time the job ran it took the last `tag` and incremented it. Since tags are different than commits, adding a tag doesn't conflict with Branch Protection.

```
# get last tag
last=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)
# increment and tag again
git tag $(($last + 1))
git push origin $(($last + 1))
```

This script is for a simple integer version number but you could follow semver if you like. This was for a Android project so I added a gradle function that would take out the last tag and use if for version number while building.

```
/*
 * Gets the version name from the latest Git tag
 */
def getVersionName = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

I am sure you could use a similar setup with Javascript.

Comment: But this doesn't commit the version id back into the project correct?

Comment: No the version info is not in the project at all. Its in the `git tag` which jenkins puts each time it sees an update on master branch. The project just knows how to take out the version info from the last `tag`. So yes there is no commiting back.

Comment: Sorry, this solution doesn't really do what I need, which is to increment the version in git. I will update the question to clarify that

Comment: This works for releasing versions from GitHub, but for R or python packages where the version is part of the code it doesn't work.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I would have to merge the version change back into prod still.